# finding the height and width of the dynamically created Imageview ?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

1. LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

imageView
    mainimage = new ImageView(HLActivity.this);
    mainimage.setLayoutParams(params);

```
loader.DisplayImage(_pageslist.get(j).getUrl(), mainimage);
```

I  already tried mainimage.getwidth() and mainimage.getHeight();

Now i want to findout the orignalwidth and height of the ImageView after
    place the image in the imageview. can you please help me.

---

Answer (score 0):

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are the indeed ones you are looking for, but you are trying to ask for the width and the height when the view is not measured yet. To fix this, we post a message to the ImageView, which will get executed after the measurement is done.

```
LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
// mark it as final, so it can be accessed in the runnable.
final imageView mainimage = new ImageView(HLActivity.this);
mainimage.setLayoutParams(params);
mainimage.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       // get the width and the height
       int width = mainimage.getWidth();
       int height = mainimage.getHeight();
       // do what you want to do with the sizes.
       loader.DisplayImage(_pageslist.get(j).getUrl(), mainimage);
    }
});
```